# JMS multiple consumers for a single queue

Tags: jms

One of our customers has a JMS based implementation in which there are queues for reading/writing messages. The JMS client needs to write to an outbound queue and the it will read the response from an inbound queue. The JMS client will be deployed across multiple sites and will talk to a single outbound queue for writing messages and will read from a inbound queue (one only) for the responses. Consider the scenario in which there are 100 unique outbound requests and then the consumer gets 100 different responses for the sent requests (assume the messages got delivered correctly). How do I ensure that the messages that the consumer is reading from the inbound queue is for the designated recipient? Do we have to write our own logic to map the request/response? or does JMS have any delivery mechanism based  on connection id … etc so that message get delivered to correct requester. Thank you very much in advance, need your expert inputs to design the application correctly. The JMS provider I am using is Apache ActiveMQ.

Regards,
Sumeet C

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need `REQUEST/REPLY`...

**Request/Reply - Synchronous**
A queue sender sends a `REQUEST` message, then in the same thread, receives a `REPLY`. The sending thread blocks until the receiver sends back a reply message, ensuring the reply is for the original request. It's a basic set up that uses temporary queues, `REPLY_TO` addressing, and `JMSCorrelationID`...

[Apache ActiveMQ Request/Reply](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html)
[EAI Patterns for JMS Request/Reply](http://www.eaipatterns.com/RequestReplyJmsExample.html)

**Point-to-Point - Async**
If the customer's JMS implementation provides distinct queues for sending requests and receiving replies, you can send messages asynchronously with a unique `JMSCorrelationID`, and provided the customer sends back a response with that same id, you can receive the response message in a different thread and correlate them with the original request based on the JMSCorrelationID. Technically-speaking, `REQUEST/REPLY` does the same thing except it blocks and uses temporary queues for sending response messages back to the requestor instead of explicitly-named queues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I can now implement the solution in a better manner